# Yii MANY_MANY on clause

Tags: database, join, yii

I have the following tables in my database.

```
subscriber(
    subscriber_id int, 
    status char(1),
    ...
)

sendlist(
    sendlist_id int,
    ...
)

subscriber_list(
   subscriber_id int,
   sendlist_id int,
   status char(1)
)
```

in my SendList model I have a relation defined as follows:

```
'Subscribers'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Subscriber', 'subscriber_list(sendlist_id, subscriber_id)',"on"=>"Subscribers_Subscribers.status='a' and Subscribers.status='a'")
```

I have tried setting both the on and condition clause, and one or the other, however the sole Subscriber in the table at present (linked to this sendlist) is ALWAYS returned, regardless of whether it's status in the subscriber table, or the subscriber_list table is set to 's'.

When I check the DB - the query that the join supposedly gives something along the lines of:

```
SELECT `Subscribers`.`subscriber_id` AS `t1_c0`, `Subscribers`.`full_phone` AS `t1_c1`, `Subscribers`.`status` AS `t1_c2`, `Subscribers`.`contact` AS `t1_c3`, `Subscribers`.`client_id` AS `t1_c4`, `Subscribers`.`date_joined` AS `t1_c5` FROM `subscriber` `Subscribers`
INNER JOIN `subscriber_list` `Subscribers_Subscribers` ON (`Subscribers_Subscribers`.`sendlist_id`=7075) AND (`Subscribers`.`subscriber_id`=`Subscribers_Subscribers`.`subscriber_id`) AND (Subscribers.status='a' and Subscribers_Subscribers.status='a') 
WHERE (Subscribers.status='a' and Subscribers_Subscribers.status='a');
```

returns an empty set (as it should). But when I print_r the $list->Subscribers array, I get the following:

```
Array(
[0] => Subscriber Object
    (
    ...
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [subscriber_id] => 2043221
                [full_phone] => 447944426885
                [status] => s
                [contact] => 0
                [client_id] => 14002
                [date_joined] => 
            )
```

so it recognises that the subscriber is status 's', but still loads it!

The code that causes the issue is here:

```
  $client = new Client();
  $client->save(false);

  //ensure that we are working with a clean subscriber set.
  $subscribers = Subscriber::model()->findAll();
  foreach($subscribers as $subscriber){
    $subscriber->delete();
  }

  //create a new subscriber with a set of filter options.
  $subscriber = new Subscriber();
  $subscriber->client_id = $client->client_id;
  $subscriber->full_phone = "44712345678";
  $subscriber->country = "England";
  $subscriber->gender = "Male";
  $subscriber->save(false);


  //create a new list with a set of matching options
  $list = new SendList();
  $list->client_id = $client->client_id;
  $list->gender = "=Male";
  $list->save(false);

  //confirm that the subscriber can be added to the list.
  self::assertTrue($list->canImport($subscriber));
  $list->import();

  //confirm that the subscriber has been added to the list.
  self::assertEquals(1, $list->active_subscriber_count);
  self::assertEquals(1, sizeof($list->Subscribers));

  //remove all subscribers (set status to 's')
  $list->remove();

  //check that the list no longer records the subscribers presence.
  self::assertEquals(0, $list->active_subscriber_count);
  self::assertEquals(1, $list->stopped_subscriber_count);

  //check that the subscriber has no lists associated with it.
  $subscriber->refresh();
  self::assertEquals('s', $subscriber->status, sizeof($subscriber->SendLists));

  //attempts to refresh the list. Tested without these with the same result.
  $list_id = $list->sendlist_id;
  unset($list);
  unset($subscriber);
  $list2 = SendList::model()->findByPk($list_id);
  $list2->refresh();

  //check that the the list has no subscribers - this fails.
  self::assertEquals(0, sizeof($list2->Subscribers));
```

Have I missed something silly?

Comment: I reproduced your tables and models, and I am able to filter data using the status column as you've described.

There is probably another part of your application causing that strange behavior.
Could you share the code involved with getting the Subscriber, and querying it's relations?

Comment: Hi @KevinHiggins I added the code of the test case that causes the issue. The test fails on the last line. I have ensured that list2 == list, so its not an issue there. I'm wondering if Yii does some funky caching somewhere?

Comment: Yii does cache the relations in the `_related` array of the CActiveRecord class. Finding a new model or refreshing the existing model will give you a fresh slate though. Consequently, you probably want to call `unset($this->Subscribers);` inside of your `$list->remove();` method, to make sure they are no longer cached. Also, seeing your `remove()` code might help as well.

Comment: I did try that, and also tried manaully getting the results from the subscriber table, without using the relationship - neither had any affect. But today, I re-ran the test case, and mysteriously - it worked. I even went back and undid all the changes I had made to the files in question (most of them were undid already), so it seems like the magic code fairies have fixed this one for me :/

Comment: Well hey, I can't say I haven't been there before. Glad it works now :).